# Jquery Dialog and Dropdown Boxes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

My dropdown boxes are showing through a jquery modal popup dialog, how do I fix this? I am using IE6 and Jquery 1.3.2 and I have the dialog bgiframe set to true.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have the actual bgiframe plugin included on your page? I'm pretty sure you still need that.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bgiframe

Comment: That was it, I needed to add the bgiframe project to the page.-Thanks.

Comment: Still kind of odd... It works but makes all my dropdowns on the page vanish while the popup is there. But the jquery datapicker you can still see the dropdowns behind it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try setting the z-index property on your modal div to something high, like 10.

```
#modalDialogID { z-index: 10; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure with IE 6 drop down lists show through no matter what the z-index.  A work around would be to hide the drop down list/inputs involved when you initiate modal popup.

Link outlining the problem which effects IE6 and 7 wow.

http://jonathanstegall.com/2009/01/15/ie-z-index-bug-with-css-dropdown-menu/